# When do you eject a reactjs application

Tags: reactjs

I have built a reactJS application npx create-react-app.

Currently I have ejected the application because I need to use the copy webpack plugin. For that, I need to get access to the configuration files.

The question is,

- Is it a good practice to eject the application?
- Will there be any any issue because of this?
- Under what circumstances do you run "npm run eject"

Comment: I normally eject when I want to add a custom webpack configuration and as far as I know it does not lead to any issues but it cannot pack it again

Comment: don't eject unless it's absolutely necessary. If you just need to copy the configuration look at this answer on how to find the configuration: [where is create-react-app webpack config and files?](//stackoverflow.com/a/48396154)

Comment: Read a good [article](https://medium.com/curated-by-versett/dont-eject-your-create-react-app-b123c5247741) on this a while back. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

- There is no real recommended practice for this. If you feel the need to override your configurations, then do it. Otherwise, there's no reason to do so.
- There will be no harmful effects from ejecting. Your build is simply going from being wrapped in a single dependency to its actual component parts.
- Usually you would run eject when you want to override something in the configuration. For example if you want to use your copy-webpack-plugin. Or want to use custom aliases. Or any other plugin/function/tweak to your configurations

Answer (score 0):

You don't need eject your application.

See this lib: https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired

`Override create-react-app webpack configs without ejecting`

You will need to eject when you work in a very specific way.

Today, we have any ways to work without eject your application :)

Comment: While that is true, it is actually not recommended to do this. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/99#issuecomment-234657710

Comment: Really, I had not seen this review. But I'm using it on projects that are in production and I've never had a problem! Thank you for alerting us

Comment: It's pretty  amusing...if you look at the first section of the README you see a quote from Dan Abramov 'stuff can break'. A quote that Adam Rackis, the owner of customize-cra specfically asked for. [Here's a link to that](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1045809734069170176)